# \arrow{} need to make thicker arrows

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I am trying to create a 6*5 foot poster where I am using text size of 48. Now when I am using `chemfig`, the arrows in relation to text are really small.
I tried using `\setarrowdefault{...thick}` but it dosen't give me satisfactory results.

I tried using `\definearrow`, but couldn't work my way through it. Can any one please help make my arrows stand out. Example in picture. 
And my MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mychemistry}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\enablefixedbondlength \setarrowoffset{20pt}
\setarrowdefault{,,,thick}
\schemestart
(i)
\chemfig{S} {\small (s)}
\+{-0.25em,-0.2em,0pt}
\chemfig{O_2} {\small (g)}
\arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->}[,0.5]
\chemfig{SO_2} {\small (g)}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}\disablefixedbondlength
%-------------------------------------------------
\newline
\enablefixedbondlength \setarrowoffset{20pt}
\schemestart
(ii)
\chemfig{2SO_2} {\small (g)}
\+{-0.25em,-0.2em,0pt}
\chemfig{O_2} {\small (g)}
\arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\small \chemfig{V_2O_5}]}[,0.6]
\chemfig{2SO_3} {\small (g)}
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}\disablefixedbondlength
%-------------------------------------------------
\newline
\enablefixedbondlength \setarrowoffset{20pt}
\schemestart
(iii)
\chemfig{SO_3}
\+{-0.25em,-0.2em,0pt}
\chemfig{H_2SO_4}
\arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\small \chemfig{V_2O_5}]}[,0.6]
\chemname[0.5ex]{\chemfig{H_2S_2O_7}}{\small Oleum}
\arrow(start.mid east--.mid west){->[\small \chemfig{H_2O}][\small Dilution]}[,0.65]
\chemfig{H_2SO_4} 
\schemestop
\chemnameinit{}\disablefixedbondlength
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make your example compilable?

Comment: Sorry I missed the document class,
Yes I will put the compilable MWE

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you compile it, but using your code (after fixing the header) I get this output:

[image]

I guess this is not what you want, or?

A "simplified version" of the first line of your reaction/code (which I find unnecessarily overcomplicated) can look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

(i)\schemestart[0,1,line width=2mm]
\chemfig{S} {\small (s)}
\+{-0.25em,-0.2em,0pt}
\chemfig{O_2} {\small (g)}
\arrow
\chemfig{SO_2} {\small (g)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Observe that instead of "thick" in the definition of arrow, you can use any tikz style, i.e., for line thickness modify `line width`. This produces:
[image]